# spark-submit on yarn - multiple jobs

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I would like to submit multiple spark-submit jobs with yarn.  When I run

`spark-submit --class myclass --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster blah blah`

as it is now, I have to wait for the job to complete for me to submit more jobs. I see the heartbeat:

`16/09/19 16:12:41 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1474313490816_0015 (state: RUNNING)
16/09/19 16:12:42 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1474313490816_0015 (state: RUNNING)`

How can I tell yarn to pick up another job all from the same terminal. Ultimately I want to be able to run from a script where I cand send hundreds of jobs in one go.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to run this easily. Did you try running this job in background, i.e. with '&'

Answer (score 3):

Every user has a fixed capacity as specified in the yarn configuration. If you are allocated N executors (usually, you will be allocated some fixed number of `vcores`), and you want to run 100 jobs, you will need to specify the allocation to each of the jobs:

`spark-submit --num-executors N/100 --executor-cores 5`

Otherwise, the jobs will loop in accepted.

You can launch multiple jobs in parallel using `&` at the last of every invocation.

`for i in`seq 20`; do spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors N/100 --executor-cores 5 blah blah &; done`

Comment: thank you @axiom yes I got that part. The problem is that i can only submit one at a time. Example: ```for i in `seq 20` ; do spark-submit --master yarn blah blah ; done``` only submits one at a time and not the 20 because its waiting for the termination signal from spark-submit.

Answer (score 1):

- Check **dynamic allocation** in spark
- Check what scheduler is in use with Yarn, if **FIFO** change it to **FAIR**
- How are you planning to allocate resources to **N** number of jobs on yarn?

Comment: dynamic allocation would be helpful since you would be running multiple jobs at a time and apps need to re-adjust their sizes according to the cluster load.